# Stream builder removing image data when updating

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stream builder that fetches data from firebase and displays them using a `ListView.builder` and some tiles are images, the problem is that every time the stream builder updates the data of the images gets discarded and the app has to fetch them back, I tried using a `Map` outside my `build` method to temporarily store the images but the `listView` still has to re-render the image tile, briefly showing a null error each time the `StreamBuilder` updates.

I am looking for a way to keep the image widgets loaded or "alive" even when the state updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by storing the image file temporarily inside a `Map` to make fetching them near instant, and there is no noticeable delay between when the `buidler` updates and the image shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package for that

Comment: I store the images locally in the device storage to reduce cost and time, is there an equivalent to cached_network_image for file images?

Comment: If you store images locally why the app fetches it from server every time? It looks like an error somewhere in logic rather an issue with images.

Comment: It's not fetching the images from the database, this part works fine, the problem is that every time the stream builder updates it "deletes"  the state of the image, and the app has to fetch them back from sotrage and redraw the widget